# Make content expand into empty div

Tags: javascript, php, css, drupal, themes

I use Drupal, Wordpress and Boostrap.

I am looking for the best solution for a div to expand horizontally on the right when the sibling div is empty.

Drupal seems to do it by itself on good themes, but I can't figure out how to do it with Wordpress and Boostrap themes.

Should this be done with PHP, JavaScript or CSS? And how?

Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can build this layout with CSS flexbox.

Basically, using flex properties, you can tell an element to share space with siblings, or consume free space when a sibling is empty or removed.

In the following example, the first version has two elements with content. In the second version, one element is empty. Everything else is the same.

```css
* { box-sizing: border-box; }

article {
    display: flex;
    border: 2px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
}

section {
    flex: 1 1 auto;  /* can grow, can shrink, start at content size */
    border: 1px dashed red;
    padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<article>
    <section>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</section>
    <section>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text</section>
</article>

<hr>

<article>
    <section>text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text text </section>
    <section></section>
</article>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zjzjk3q2/)

Answer (score 0):

I would use Javascript, do this for a small fix.

```
<div>
<div id='item1'>Stuff Here</div>
<div id='item2'>Stuff Here</div>
</div>
<script>
    var sibling = document.getElementById("item1").nextSibling;
    if (sibling.innerHTML.length === 0) {
            sibling.parentNode.removeChild(sibling);
            document.getElementById("item1").style.width = "100%";
    }
</script>
```

Underneath the divs...